# Objectify/AppEngine/Java: Many-many relationship

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I use Objectify in AppEngine with JAva. I would like to model a many-many relationship in which the resolution entity has additional fields, as below

```
@Entity
public class Account {
    public @Id Long id;
    public String name;
}

@Entity
public class Baby {
    @Id public Long id;
    public String name;
}

@Entity
public class AccountBaby {
    public @Id Long id;
    @Index
    @ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
    public Ref<Account> account;

    @Index
    @ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
    public Ref<Baby> baby;

    public int permission;
}
```

If I follow this model, I can not query list of account for given baby's id (or list of baby for given account's id) as the query below

```
List<AccountBaby> babies = OfyService.ofy().load().type(AccountBaby.class).filter("account=",
                Key.create(Account.class, accountId)).list();
```

Is they any other way to query or model this relationship?

Answer (score 3):

You need a space in "account =". Or you can just leave off the "=", which is implied.

What you're actually searching for is a property which is literally named "account=" (which can be saved in the datastore with the low level api). This is mentioned in the javadocs for the `filter()` method.